# why np.vectorize(max) does not work as expected

Tags: python, numpy, max

I have the following code

```
import numpy as np
f = np.vectorize(lambda x: max(x, 0))
print(f(-0.3))
print(f(1.8))
print(f([1.8, -0.3]))
print(f([-0.3, 1.8]))
```

I have the output:

```
0
1.8
[1.8 0. ]
[0 1]
```

Could any one explain why I get [0 1] for f([-0.3, 1.8])

I just do another test:

```
print(type(f([3])[0]))
print(f([3, 1.5]))
```

now I get

```
<class 'numpy.int32'>
[3.  1.5]
```

If the data type of the output of vectorized is determined by calling the function with the first element of the input. why the second case works as expected?

Comment: `0` is an integer.  If you use `max(x, 0.0)`, it works as you expect.

Comment: You get the integer version when the first case returns the integer `0`, i.e. when the first element is negative.  The `vectorize` docs should be clear (enough) on this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It's dangerous to use `np.vectorize` without reading full docs - or at least annoying.

The return dtype is determined by the first test case:

```
In [52]: np.vectorize(lambda x: max(x,0))(np.linspace(-1,1,6))
Out[52]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Note the integer values.  With a float value:

```
In [53]: np.vectorize(lambda x: max(x,0.0))(np.linspace(-1,1,6))
Out[53]: array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.6, 1. ])
```

Or setting it explicitly:

```
In [54]: np.vectorize(lambda x: max(x,0),otypes=['f'])(np.linspace(-1,1,6))
Out[54]: array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.6, 1. ], dtype=float32)
```

But for a function like this, skip `vectorize` entirely:

```
In [55]: np.maximum(np.linspace(-1,1,6),0)
Out[55]: array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.6, 1. ])
```

Often a list comprehension is just as good as `vectorize`:

```
In [56]: np.array([max(x,0) for x in np.linspace(-1,1,6)])
Out[56]: array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2, 0.6, 1. ])
```

Time tests generally show that the list comprehension is faster for most cases.  The current version of `vectorize` does have a modest speed advantage for very large array.  But the properly "vectorized" version, as in [55], is best for all sizes.

Often `vectorize` is used with a function that involves `if/else` clauses, since they only work with scalar values.  Returning a integer value for one of those cases is a common mistake.

```
In [57]: def foo(x):
    ...:     if x<0:
    ...:         return 0
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return x
    ...: 
In [58]: np.vectorize(foo)(np.linspace(-1,1,6))
Out[58]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling the
> function with the first element of the input. This can be avoided by
> specifying the `otypes` argument.

So since the output of the first is a `int` object, it infers `numpy.int64` as the output dtype.

More importantly, though, you probably should just not be using `numpy.vectorize` here, it doesn't really make any sense. Why are you using it, if I might ask? Keep in mind another important part of the docs:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
> performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Comment: I just do this for for convenience. e.g.
`x = np.linspace(0,10,101)`
`plot(x, f(x))`

Comment: @JTonik well just so you know `numpy.max` already exists

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why, but I think vectorize isn't too bright about distinguishing data types.  Change "0" to "0.0" and you may get better results.

Comment: `vectorize` does a test calculation to determine the return dtype.  Returning a 0 for first case makes an integer dtype.  You can specify a return `otypes`.  Or if you want it to return a dtype based on all values, use `np.array([foo(x) for x in arr])`.  That's just as good, especially for smallish cases.